# while usb debugging the app communication with server was working fine but while in production its not working what could be the issue?

Tags: python, android, react-native

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { GiftedChat, Bubble } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import { AuthContext, useAuth } from '../AuthContext';
import { View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const ChatScreen = ({route}) => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const recipient = route.params.recipient;
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  const onSend = (newMessages = []) => {
    let currentMessage = newMessages[0].text;
    const sendingMessage = {
      _id: newMessages[0]._id || Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
      text: currentMessage,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      user: {
        _id: user.username,
        name: user.username,
      },
    };
    setMessages((prevMessages) => GiftedChat.append(prevMessages, [sendingMessage]));
    if (currentMessage.trim() && recipient.trim()) {
      socket.emit('message', { recipient: recipient, msg: currentMessage });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const socketInstance = io('<ip-address>', {
      query: { userId: user.username },
    });
    setSocket(socketInstance);
  
    socketInstance.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Socket connected');
    });
  
    socketInstance.on('message', (message) => {
      const incomingMessage = {
        _id: message._id || Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
        text: message,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        user: {
          _id: recipient,
          name: recipient,
        },
      };
      setMessages((prevMessages) => GiftedChat.append(prevMessages, [incomingMessage]));
    });
  
    return () => {
      if (socketInstance) {
        socketInstance.disconnect();
        console.log('Socket disconnected');
      }
    };
  
  }, [recipient, messages]);
  
  const renderBubble = (props) => {
    return (
      <Bubble
        {...props}
        wrapperStyle={{
          left: {
            backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
          },
          right: {
            backgroundColor: '#007BFF',
            marginRight: -5,
          },
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text style={styles.heading}>Your's {user.username == 'test' ? 'test' : 'wow'}</Text>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 10 }}>
        <GiftedChat
          messages={messages}
          onSend={(newMessages) => onSend(newMessages)}
          user={{
            _id: user.username,
            name: user.username,
          }}
          renderBubble={renderBubble}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  heading: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
  },
});

export default ChatScreen;
```

Server side is okay its working fine while i test it from usb debugging.after buld i installed the apk but the server is not getting the request from the app in my phone that i have installed. while usb debugging the app communication with server was working fine but while in production its not working what could be the issue? please help me in this

```
01-22 14:53:03.883 15230 15230 D g       : setAlphabetAutomaticShiftedKeyboard
01-22 14:53:03.890 15230 15230 D kalsessionstart: com.love
01-22 14:53:03.891 15230 15230 W FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'group'.
01-22 14:53:03.891 15230 15230 W FirebaseRemoteConfig: No value of type 'String' exists for parameter key 'event_map'.
01-22 14:53:03.894 13339 13355 I Finsky  : [397405] py.ae(66): com.clusterdev.malayalamkeyboard: Account determined from installer data - [_mpukSYwNRwRnez-YGS3c0h1se5Q8Q5VSQfZFibakUg]
01-22 14:53:03.895  1019  1019 I SDM     : HWCDisplayBuiltIn::GetOptimalRefreshRate: active_refresh_rate_: 60
01-22 14:53:03.896 13339 13355 I Finsky  : [397405] ljw.a(907): Billing preferred account via installer for com.clusterdev.malayalamkeyboard: [_mpukSYwNRwRnez-YGS3c0h1se5Q8Q5VSQfZFibakUg]
01-22 14:53:03.903 15230 15230 I SoftKeyboard: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
01-22 14:53:03.903 15230 15230 D StatsUtils: onStartInputView: 147457
01-22 14:53:03.906 18474 18474 W IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-22 14:53:03.912 18474 18474 W IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
01-22 14:53:03.912  1019  1019 I SDM     : HWCDisplayBuiltIn::GetOptimalRefreshRate: active_refresh_rate_: 60
01-22 14:53:03.913 18474 18474 W IInputConnectionWrapper: requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
01-22 14:53:03.913 18474 18474 W IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-22 14:53:03.914 15230 15230 E RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.
01-22 14:53:03.914 15230 15230 D RichInputConnection: Will try to retrieve text later.
01-22 14:53:03.914 18474 18474 W IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-22 14:53:03.914 15230 15230 E RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.
01-22 14:53:03.914 15230 15230 W RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor. Setting caps mode without knowing text.
01-22 14:53:03.915 18474 18474 W IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
01-22 14:53:03.915 15230 15230 E RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor to retrieve text.
01-22 14:53:03.915 15230 15230 W RichInputConnection: Unable to connect to the editor. Setting caps mode without knowing text.
01-22 14:53:03.915 15230 15230 D g       : requestUpdatingShiftState:  autoCapsFlags=sentences recapitalizeMode=undefined
```

logcat error

Comment: The problem might be that the endpoint is not encrypted android requires https.

Comment: @Robert added the logcat error